# What is the difference between gets() and getch()?

Tags: c++, gets, getch

I've heard of both function but I've never really understood their differences. Is `gets()`
for getting a string without pressing enter and `getch()` for getting only one character without pressing enter?

Thanks

Comment: Also, it should be easy to search for both and compare the documentation.

Comment: are you familiar with man pages?

Comment: one gets an 's', and the other gets a 'ch'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getch()` is a function in `conio.h` on windows and DOS systems that's not standardized in C. It's used to get only (exactly) a single character. It also exists in `curses.h` on *nix systems (according to Mike in the comments).

`gets()` is a standard function in C, which got removed in the new `C11` standard. You can use it to input a string, but you should **never use it**. You can't use it to safely input a string, because it writes to memory as long as you type. So you can get buffer overflows quite easily.

Comment: Right on, about gets().  Rather, you should use fgets() and specify the max length as the second argument and stdin for the third argument, as a clean and safe replacement for gets().

Comment: `getch` is **not** a Window's only function. It's availbe in `curses.h` for *ix

Answer (score 0):

> I've never really understood their differences

Those methods have clearly different signatures (that resemble the semantics quite obviously IMHO):

```
 char *gets( char *str );

 int getch(void);
```

Note that `getch()` is platform specific notation, the equivalent standard defined `getc()` function wants a `FILE*` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The `getch` is a platform or compiler specific function.

The `gets` function is used for returning zero or more characters from the standard (console) input.

**Edit 1:**
Depending on your compiler implementation, the `getch` function may be used to get a character without waiting for the user or to get a character without echoing to the console.

One function gets single character, the other gets many.

Answer (score -1):

`gets()` has been removed in C11 and marked as deprecated in C++11.

I've not heard of `getch()`. Do you mean `getchar()`?

In any case, you should be able to look up documentation yourself. Those two functions are part of `cstdio`

Comment: IIRC, getch is from conio (DOS).